# Double-quote match between pattern1 and first pattern2 and replace newlines within a file (output whole file)

Tags: awk, sed

#### Problem definition

I’d like to capture a multiline substring from a file (or `STDIN`), double-quote it and replace all newlines (`\n` → `\\n`) within it (not outside of it).

There might be several start and end patterns in the file; I want to modify all of instances. Some instances might be on a single line.

I prefer GNU `sed` to GNU `awk` (just because I use `sed` more than `awk`, however, it does not matter which one will be used in the solution, just make it work in Bash on Linux.

#### Example of the matched substring

```js
date: await (async (y: number): Promise<Dayjs> => {
  const firstDayOfOT = dayjs((await Seasons.earlyOrdinaryTime(y, config.epiphanyOnSunday))[0].date);
  return firstDayOfOT.add(2, 'week').startOf('week');
})(year),
```

#### What I have tried

I have tried the following command, but `sed` is greedy, i.e. it matches *last* end match and therefore does not work when there are more than one instances. Also note that this command only double-quotes the captured match; it does not replaces newlines.

```sh
sed -n '1h; 1!H; ${ g; s/date: \(await.*[(]year[)]\)/date: "\1"/p }' file
```

#### Bonus points

While above I have talked about a *single* start/end pattern pair, actually, there are three (plus two one-liner variations of one them), see below. Note that I have removed the indentation (it actually does not matter, as it can be easily batched by `^\s*`).

If you are eager enough to help me out, you can include these patterns too.

```js
date: ((y: number): dayjs.Dayjs => {
  const date = dayjs.utc(`${y}-11-1`);
  if (date.day() === 6) {
    return dayjs.utc(`${y}-11-2`);
  } else {
    return date;
  }
})(year),
```

```js
date: await (async (y: number): Promise<Dayjs> => {
  const firstDayOfOT = dayjs((await Seasons.earlyOrdinaryTime(y,
    config.epiphanyOnSunday))[0].date);
  return firstDayOfOT.add(2, 'week').startOf('week');
})(year)
```

```js
date: ((): dayjs.Dayjs => {
  const firstDay = dayjs.utc(`${year}-1-1`);
  const feastDay = 22 - (firstDay.day() == 0 ? 7 : firstDay.day());
  return dayjs.utc(`${year}-1-${feastDay}`);
})(),
```

```js
// One-liners
date: ((y: number): Dayjs => Dates.pentecostSunday(y).add(1, 'day'))(year),

date: ((y: number): dayjs.Dayjs => Dates.pentecostSunday(y).add(1, 'day'))(year),
```

#### Why do I need this?

I’d like to parse the *calendar* files from [here](https://github.com/romcal/romcal/tree/_F-TypeScript/src/calendars) (all those files except for `index.ts` and `test.ts`). I wish `jq` could parse TypeScript objects (or whatever they are called), but because it can’t do that, I want to ‘convert’ it using [`hjson`](https://hjson.github.io/) to a proper JSON string and then parse it using `jq`.

Now, in order to make the file(s) ‘convertable’ by `hjson`, I need to do the following:

- remove lines above `const _dates: Array<RomcalLiturgicalDayInput>` (including);
- remove lines below `Get localized liturgical day names` (including);
- format arrays:

  - `hjson` does not like the square brackets on the same line as the array items (they must be on separate lines);
  - each array item must be on a separate line;
  - when not quoted, each array item *must not* be followed by a comma, otherwise that comma becomes part of the array item;
- no value can be a multiline one *unless* newlines are replaced by `\\n`;
- if special characters (interpreted by TS/JS, e.g. `{}[]`, backtick or even a comma) are included, that value must be quoted.

Except for the final two, I have already done this. See the following command (`general.ts` is from [here](https://github.com/romcal/romcal/blob/_F-TypeScript/src/calendars/general.ts)). Note that I am sure that this could be optimised and perfected.

```sh
sed '1,/const _dates: Array<RomcalLiturgicalDayInput> = \[/d;/Get localized liturgical day names/,$d' general.ts | \
  sed -z 's/^/[\n/;s/\];/]/; \
    s/\([^\n]\)\(Titles.[^, \n]*\),*/\1\n\2/g; \
    s/\(Titles.[^, \n]*\),*\s*\]/\1\n]/g; \
    s/\([^\n]\)\(LiturgicalColors.[^, \n]*\),*/\1\n\2/g; \
    s/\(LiturgicalColors.[^, \n]*\),*\s*\]/\1\n]/g; \
    s/\(cycles: {\) \(celebrationCycle: CelebrationsCycle.TEMPORALE\) \(}\)/\1\n\2\n\3/g' | \
  sed -n '1h; 1!H; ${ g; s/date: \(await.*[(]year[)]\)/date: "\1"/p }' | less
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^date: \(await\|((y: number):\|(():\)/{
      :a;/\((year)\|()\),\?$/!{N;ba};s/\n/\\n/g;s/.*/"&"/}' file
```

Gather up lines beginning with `date:` and either `await`, `((y: number):` or `(():` and lines ending `(year)` or `()` with or without a `,`. Then replace all `\n` by `\\n` and surround the collection by double quotes.

This may need some tweaking to satisfy all your requirements.

Comment: Thanks, @potong! It works quite nicely, however, it puts `date: ` into the double quotes, but that is not part of the value (it is the key _name_). Anyway, I think that we could eliminate checking the start pattern (expect for `date: `), because I think all `date` key values should be quoted. And end pattern could be simplified to ``([year]*)|`)`` (trailing comma is not part of the value, therefore should not be quoted). → ``sed '/^date: /{:a;/\(([year]*)\|`)\),\?$/!{N;ba};s/\n/\\n/g;s/.*/"&"/}'``

Comment: AFAIK, there is no such thing as _negative lookbehind_ in GNU `sed`; do you know of another way to deal with this?

Comment: Another issue is that if I use the following command on the [`general.ts`](https://github.com/romcal/romcal/blob/_F-TypeScript/src/calendars/general.ts) file, it replaces the `date` elements with strange output (it somehow merges multiple `date` element values or what). The command: ``sed '1,/const _dates: Array<RomcalLiturgicalDayInput> = \[/d;/Get localized liturgical day names/,$d' general.ts | sed '/^\s*date: /{:a;/\(([year]*)\|()\),\?$/!{N;ba};s/\n/\\n/g;s/.*/"&"/}' | less`` … … [My output](https://pastebin.com/3K348tvQ)